# Passing Parameter to Angular Factory from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm

I couldn't pass the parameter from angular controller to factory. Can any one help me on this? It works without passing parameter but when I pass it it's not.

```
var app = angular.module('employee', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.saveState', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid.autoResize','ui.grid.pagination']);

app.controller('EmpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$modal', '$log', 'gridService', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $modal, $log, gridService) {
    $scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage("5");
}]);

var gridService = function ($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        LoadNextPage: function (hh) {
            alert(hh);
        },
        gridOptions:gridOptions
    };
};

app.factory('gridService', ['$http', '$rootScope', gridService]);
```

And this is how I use it in the view

```
<span id="pcNext"
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"
      ng-click="LoadNextPage()">
</span>
```

Comment: when I click the button It didn't work when I pass the parameter..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your controller:

```
$scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage("5");
```

This means that your `LoadNextPage` is **not a function** but rather a result of the call to a function in your service. Which btw doesn't return anything but rather just displays an alert. But in your view, you're using `LoadNextPage` as a function call...

Change it to this so your controller's `LoadNextPage` will be a function that you can call from the view.

```
$scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage;
```

and in your view:

```
<span id="pcNext"
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"
      ng-click="LoadNextPage(5)">
</span>
```

This should work.

> ***Note***: I suspect that your `gridOptions` are defined somewhere outside of scope of your code that you provided in the question so that it doesn't throw and error because of the missing (likely) object. So I considered this a typo in your code and not the actual problem.

### Don't want params in your view?

No problem. You can either create a wrapper function or bind it to specific parameters in your code:

```
// wrap
$scope.LoadNextPage = function() {
    return gridService.LoadNextPage("5");
};

// bind
$scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage.bind(this, 5);
```

Or *bake* the number in your service...

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is `gridOptions:gridOptions` is not defined which throws error. 
Remove `,gridOptions:gridOptions` from `factory`.

Check snippet for working code and compare with your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('employee', []);
app.controller('EmpCtrl', ['$scope', 'gridService', function ($scope, gridService) {
 $scope.clickMe = function() {
   $scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage("5");
 }
}]);
var gridService = function() {
  return {
    LoadNextPage: function (hh) {
     alert(hh);
   }
 };
};
app.factory('gridService', ['$http', '$rootScope', gridService]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="employee" ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clickMe()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you not defined **gridOptions** function see this link:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCon", function($scope, $interval, gridService){

  $scope.LoadNextPage = gridService.LoadNextPage("5");
}).factory('gridService', ['$http', '$rootScope', gridService]);

function gridService($http, $rootScope){
  return {
        LoadNextPage: function (hh) {
            alert(hh);
        }
    };
}
```

[see this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cXpndTmyPxejb75gss8g?p=preview)